Is ‘I screamed that she get out of there’ reported speech for “Get out of there” I screamed?
I am having some trouble using and understanding the subjunctive in English so I am in doubt regarding the correct way to use the reported speech for the next sentence

“Get out of there,” I screamed.

I wouldn't use 'gets' as it would render the sentence into the indicative
I wouldn't use 'got' as pairing 'that' and 'got' wouldn't make sense as the usage would be the past tense and not the subjunctive.
So my choice would be 'that she get out of there'.

What is your full sentence?  "He screamed that she get out of there" ?

I screamed that she get out of there. That is the full sentence. I am trying to use reported speech for 'Get out of there' I screamed.'

Scream does not typically  license a change of verb form in the subordinate clause, as 'suggest, advise, counseled' etc do.   "I suggested that she leave that job."  You could say "I screamed the advice that she get out of there."   Something to justify the change of verb semantically.

scream, shout, growl, bellow etc present the manner of speech, but you need something in the sentence to convey the idea of advice-giving.  That requirement trumps any "rule" governing reported speech.

@TimR: "I screamed the advice that she get out of there"? That is completely tone deaf. It sounds ridiculous. I suggest "I screamed at her to get out of there."

@TonyK  You're missing the point. The OP is asking about "understanding the subjunctive in English".   The sentence needs something to justify "that she get out of there".

@TimR: Yes, point taken. But it is irresponsible of you to suggest such a monstrosity to an innocent language learner! What if they took you seriously?

@TonyK  We will have to disagree on this.  It seemed that the OP was advisedly choosing the verb "scream" to test what sorts of verbs license that verb change in the subordinate clause.  And it is reported speech. Reported speech can be wooden, depending on the context. Consider a deposition, where precision can trump the idiomatic.

No, but a version that would work is I screamed for her to get out of there. Or, of course, I screamed at her, “Get out of there!”
I will add that an outdated usage of that meant what we today convey by so that or in order that. Thus, we have things like He gave his life that others might live.

Thank you! But, might you please tell me if it made sense to you in other words, Is it completely wrong or just a little odd?

It would be understood by most native speakers, but would certainly be a marker of non-native proficiency.

@PaulTanenbaum, Very good explanation and new information for us, learners, because I didn't know that the word "that" meant "so that" or "in order that.", despite being outdated.

"I asked that she be on time" seems a little old-fashioned, but reasonably correct (and it's not replaceable with "so that"). Why wouldn't "screamed" work in a construction like that?

@Maciej Because screaming does not meaning requesting/demanding. It expresses the manner in which you say something, rather than the purpose. If you use a verb that indicates a request or order, then you can use the subjunctive to introduce what is being requested or ordered; but you cannot do that with just any speech verb. You also wouldn’t say, “*I said that she be on time” or “*I whispered that she be on time” (except to mean “I whispered, so that she might be on time”… but that’s semantically very odd and sounds fairly ridiculous).
